# How to read URL in NFC in android

Tags: android, nfc, reader

I used [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) code for integrating `NFC` reading in my `android` application. Write a plain text to the `NFC` tag and read using app it is perfectly working. Now my requirement is to read `URL` from the `NFC` tag.When reading value from `NFC` tag it automatically open the browser and loading the `URL`.So what changes needed to achieve the reading content and open my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your Manifest

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <data
                android:host="your host name"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in the activity you want to open

Comment: can you please clarify me how to add the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume that results returned will be only url and no other data with it, so just modify `onPostExecute` as :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result != null) {
        String url = result;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

If other data also included than parse results to get only URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter if you want to start the app when get closer to NFC tag, but be aware if your app is running it won't be notified about the tag. You have to register it inside your app:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent nfcIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
    nfcIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    nfcPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nfcIntent, 0);

    IntentFilter tagIntentFilter =
            new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        tagIntentFilter.addDataType("text/plain");
        intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[]{tagIntentFilter};
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and remember to enable it in onResume:

```
nfcAdpt.enableForegroundDispatch(
            this,
            nfcPendingIntent,
            intentFiltersArray,
            null);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
```

and unregister it in onPause:

nfcAdpt.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

..be aware that the data can be stored in SmartPoster structure in your NFC tag. In this case you have to read it in another way.
In my blog you can find a post about reading [SmartPoster and more](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/03/nfc-android-read-ndef-tag.html)